# JFuzzylite - Conjunctions + Suggestions

Tags: java, android, logic, fuzzy

I'm relatively new to implementing fuzzy logic.

Using jfuzzylite and input from android sensors (Z-axis acceleration and speed calculated from the phone gps), i'd like output the drivers behavior.

The java code is as follows;

```
public void fuzzyMethod(double carspeed, double acceleration){
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    engine.setName("DriverClassifier");

    /*Speed input value
      Speed range set between 0 and 95km/hr
     Three terms - slow, normal, fast
     */
    InputVariable speed = new InputVariable();
    speed.setEnabled(true);
    speed.setName("SPEED");
    speed.setRange(0.000,95.000);
    speed.addTerm(new Triangle("SLOW",0.000,25.000,50.000 ));
    speed.addTerm(new Triangle("NORMAL",40.000,52.500,65.000));
    speed.addTerm(new Triangle("FAST", 55.000, 75.000,95.000));
    engine.addInputVariable(speed);

    /*
    Accelerometer values in z-axis direction - left to right
     */
    InputVariable zaxis = new InputVariable();
    zaxis.setEnabled(true);
    zaxis.setName("ZAXISACCELERATION");
    zaxis.setRange(-4.500,4.500);

    //Deceleration
    zaxis.addTerm(new Triangle("HARDDECELERATION",1.500,3.00,4.500 ));
    zaxis.addTerm(new Triangle("DECELERATION",0.500,1.5,2.5));

    //Calm/Neutral
    zaxis.addTerm(new Triangle("NEUTRAL",-0.5,0,0.5));

    //Acceleration
    zaxis.addTerm(new Triangle("ACCELERATION",-0.500,-1.250,-2.000));
    zaxis.addTerm(new Triangle("HARDACCELERATION",-1.500,-3.000,-4.500));
    engine.addInputVariable(zaxis);


    OutputVariable drivingStyle = new OutputVariable();
    drivingStyle.setName("DRIVINGSTYLE");
        //drivingStyle.setDefuzzifier(new Centroid(200));
    drivingStyle.addTerm(new Triangle("CALM",0,0.5,1));
    drivingStyle.addTerm(new Triangle("NORMAL",1,1.5,2));
    drivingStyle.addTerm(new Triangle("AGGRESSIVE",2, 2.5, 3));
        engine.addOutputVariable(drivingStyle);



    //Set Rules
    RuleBlock ruleBlock = new RuleBlock();
    //SLOW SPEED
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is SLOW) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is HARDDECELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is SLOW) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is DECELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is NORMAL", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is SLOW) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is NEUTRAL) then DRIVINGSTYLE is NORMAL", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is SLOW) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is ACCELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is NORMAL", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is SLOW) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is HARDACCELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));


    //NORMAL SPEED
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is NORMAL) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is HARDDECELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is NORMAL) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is DECELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is NORMAL) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is NEUTRAL) then DRIVINGSTYLE is NORMAL", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is NORMAL) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is ACCELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is NORMAL) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is HARDACCELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));


    //TOO FAST
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is FAST) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is HARDDECELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is FAST) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is DECELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is FAST) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is NEUTRAL) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is FAST) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is ACCELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if (SPEED is FAST) and (ZAXISACCELERATION is HARDACCELERATION) then DRIVINGSTYLE is AGGRESSIVE", engine));
    engine.addRuleBlock(ruleBlock);

        speed.setInputValue(carspeed);
        zaxis.setInputValue(acceleration);
        //engine.configure("",  "Minimum","", "Maximum", "Centroid");
        engine.configure("Minimum","Maximum","","","Centroid");
        //ruleBlock.setConjunction(new Minimum());
        //ruleBlock.setDisjunction(new Maximum());
        //ruleBlock.setActivation(new Minimum());
        engine.process();
        Log.d("fuzzy",drivingStyle.getOutputValue()+ " ");
        //FuzzyLite.logger().info(Op.str(drivingStyle.getOutputValue()));
    }
```

Can someone guide me as to what needs to be done to achieve the desired output? At the moment, my output is D/fuzzy: NaN.

The input variables are based on values I obtained while driving- hence the defined ranges.

1. Am I using the correct terms for the application in question?
2. Are the conjunction, disjunction and activation values correct?

The following is the FLL produced;

```
Engine: Driver Classification
InputVariable: Speed
  enabled: true
  range: 0.000 95.000
  term: Slow Triangle 0.000 25.000 50.000
  term: Normal Triangle 40.000 52.500 65.000
  term: Fast Triangle 55.000 75.500 95.000
InputVariable: Acceleration
  enabled: true
  range: -4.500 4.500
  term: HardDeceleration Triangle 1.500 3.000 4.500
  term: Deceleration Triangle 0.500 1.500 2.500
  term: Neutral Triangle -0.500 0.000 0.500
  term: Acceleration Triangle -2.000 -1.250 -0.500
  term: HardDeceleration Triangle -4.500 -3.000 -1.500
OutputVariable: DrivingStyle
  enabled: true
  range: 0.000 1.000
  accumulation: none
  defuzzifier: WeightedSum
  default: nan
  lock-valid: false
  lock-range: false
  term: Calm Triangle 0.000 0.250 0.500
  term: Normal Triangle 0.250 0.500 0.750
  term: Aggressive Triangle 0.500 0.750 1.000
RuleBlock: 
  enabled: true
  conjunction: Minimum
  disjunction: Maximum
  activation: Minimum
  rule: if Speed is Slow and Acceleration is HardDeceleration then DrivingStyle is Aggressive
  rule: if Speed is Slow and Acceleration is Deceleration then DrivingStyle is Calm
  rule: if Speed is Slow and Acceleration is Neutral then DrivingStyle is Calm
  rule: if Speed is Slow and Acceleration is Acceleration then DrivingStyle is Calm
  rule: if Speed is Slow and Acceleration is HardDeceleration then DrivingStyle is Aggressive
  rule: if Speed is Normal and Acceleration is HardDeceleration then DrivingStyle is Aggressive
  rule: if Speed is Normal and Acceleration is Deceleration then DrivingStyle is Normal
  rule: if Speed is Normal and Acceleration is Neutral then DrivingStyle is Calm
  rule: if Speed is Normal and Acceleration is Acceleration then DrivingStyle is Normal
  rule: if Speed is Normal and Acceleration is HardDeceleration then DrivingStyle is Aggressive
  rule: if Speed is Fast and Acceleration is HardDeceleration then DrivingStyle is Aggressive
  rule: if Speed is Fast and Acceleration is Deceleration then DrivingStyle is Aggressive
  rule: if Speed is Fast and Acceleration is Neutral then DrivingStyle is Aggressive
  rule: if Speed is Fast and Acceleration is Acceleration then DrivingStyle is Aggressive
  rule: if Speed is Fast and Acceleration is HardDeceleration then DrivingStyle is Aggressive
```

Thanks in advance !

Regards,
Steven Farrugia